# Renaming files/dir's from one date format to another

Tags: date, awk, terminal, grep, rename

So I am a coding newbie and have, for some time, wanted to edit the formatting of my fairly extensive live music library. I have looked around on here and various other resources to get to where I am, but I have hit a snag. I have directories named in the following ways:

- 02.10.90 | 23 East Caberet - Ardmore, PA
- 02.16.90 | The Paradise - Boston, MA

and I would like to rename these simply to

- 1990-02-10 | 23 East Caberet - Ardmore, PA
- 1990-02-16 | The Paradise - Boston, MA

I have been able to rename the date correctly using:

```
ls -1 | grep 90 |  awk '{print $1}' | awk  -F. '{printf "%s-%s-%s\n", "19"$3,$1,$2}' > list1.txt
```

and then pull the rest of the name using

```
ls -1 | grep 90 | awk '{first = $1; $1 = ""; print $0}'>list2.txt
```

So, I have a list of directories ranging from years 1990-2004 that I would like to apply this to (they are all in different sub directories so I don't mind manually changing the "grep 90". However, from the two separate lists that I generate, I cant figure out how to make it loop through each row and print "mv original_name list1.txt+list2.txt" so that it would read:

```
mv 02.10.90 | 23 East Caberet - Ardmore, PA 1990-02-10 | 23 East Caberet - Ardmore, PA
```

I scanned through many previous posts and couldn't quite figure out the last bit - or better yet, a more elegant solution! Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse the output from `ls`, google why, and you don't need grep when you're using awk, nor do you need chains of awk commands but for this task you wouldn't use any of those commands anyway.

The UNIX command to find files is named `find` so start with that. This will find all directories with names starting with the given globbing pattern:

```
find . -type d -name '[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].90 *'
```

Now that you've found the files you need to do something with them. For your needs IMHO the simplest approach is best and that'd be:

```
find . -type d -name '[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].90 *' -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' old; do
    path="$(dirname "$old")"
    oldDirName="$(basename "$old")"
    if [[ oldDirName =~ ([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)( .*) ]]; then
        newDirName="19${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
        echo mv -- "${path}/${oldDirName}" "${path}/${newDirName}"
    fi
done
```

The above is using GNU find for -print0 and bash for BASH_REMATCH. Remove the `echo` when you've debugged it if necessary and are happy with what it's going to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That provides much insight on my problem - the one thing I didn't mention is that I am running Mac OS Sierra and don't think that the GNU commands will work in my bash. I will try messing around with it to see if I can get it to work though.

Comment: You can install GNU tools on a Mac. Google it. Otherwise, if your file names do not contain newlines than remove the `-print0` from find and `-d ''` from read and the rest should work as-is.